# C++ Comparing descendants of abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, abstract, overriding, virtual-functions

Yes, I know it's bad tone to compare different descendants of abstract class. But I *really* have to.

I have this simple abstract class:

```
class Figure {
    public:
    virtual double Square() = 0;
    virtual ~Figure() {};
}
```

What I want to add to it is something like:

```
bool operator<(const Figure& other) {};
```

Which would compare its descendants - geometric figures, namely `Triangle, Rectangle, Octagon` - using their area returned in method `Square()`.

Is that possible in any way?

Comment: I am trying to figure out what is stopping you here.

Comment: You are not comparing descendants of anything. You are comparing numbers. An area is a number. You can have a virtual `area` method in `Figure` (no idea why anyone would call it `Square`), just call it.

Comment: @drescherjm I probably got something wrong here, but when I write `return (*this->Square() < other->Square());` like I would in descendant class, I get `"invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘double’)"` error

Comment: `return (Square() < other.Square());` Also you'll need to make `Square()` and `operator<` const methods.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of `*` in `*this->Square()`.

Comment: @n.m. passing reference to object I'm working with. is it unnecessary?

Comment: You need to learn about pointers and references and `this` and ->` and `.`, otherwise you cannot make much sense. Passing reference where exactly? What expects a reference? If you read the error message carefully, you may notice that it talks about `double`, which is what your `*` is applied. Your `Square` method returns a `double`. Perhaps, you might think, `*this->Square()` is parsed as `*(this->Square())` and not as `(*this)->Square()` as I thought?

Comment: Next time please post the implementation that is causing the error along with the error message in your question.

Comment: @drescherjm Point taken! Sorry that my question was unclear. I try to stick to guidelines, but I'm a bit new to this...

Comment: By the way, you don't want to compare descendants of an abstract or base class since they could be anything.  For example, if you derive Hexagon from figure, you would be comparing a Square with a Hexagon, which doesn't make sense.  A better design is to have an `Area` function in the base class that returns the area of a `Figure`.  You can then compare areas of figures which makes more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comment `return (*this->Square() < other->Square());` your trouble simply seems to be basic syntax.

`this` is a simple pointer. So the typical correct syntax is just `this->Square()`. Of course since it's inside a member function then `this` can be omitted entirely as just `Square()`.

`other` is a reference, so that uses the dot operator as `other.Square()`

Another useful thing, potentially relevant to your latest comment, is to make the operator< function `const` since it isn't modifying the the object it's being called on.

So the resulting code should be something more like:

```
bool operator<(const Figure& other) const
{
    return Square() < other.Square();
}
```

Comment: I think I understand `this` a bit more now... Yes, I've actually changed `->` to `.` before.
I also had to make `Square()` const, like @jimvonmoon suggested, for this to work.
Thanks for clearing things up!